# Django получить связанные данные

Tags: python, django

Задача: Необходимо получить список активных адресов не связанных ни с одним активным документом (если у документа указан признак активности False адрес должен попасть в выборку).

```
class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Documents(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    address = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Каким образом лучше реализовать данную задачу?